# if statements not behaving as anticipated

Tags: c

We had to make a short questionnaire type program for an assignment and when I run this it prints the first if statement before you even input anything. Then it prints the rest of the statements including the if statement for option 1 once again before any input is received. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h

int main()

{

    char reply = 0;
    char yes = 0;
    char no = 0;
    char name = 0;
    int option = 0;


    printf("Hey M!\n");
    printf("Is today your 16th birtday?!\n:yes or no\n");


    if (reply == yes) {
        printf("HAPPY BIRTHDAY!! :)\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Are you sure??\n");
    }

    scanf("%c", &reply);

    printf("It is time for your super awesome birthday surprise\n\n");
    printf("You must choose between one of two presents\n\n");
    printf("Please choose between the following options:\n Option 1 or Option 2\n (enter a 1 or a 2)\n\n");

    if (option == 1) {
        printf("Go look in Mom and Dad's closet!!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Go look in the storage room!!");
    }
    scanf("%d", &option);

    printf("HAVE A GREAT SWEET 16!");

    return 0;
```

Comment: right, because you coded so..

Comment: a single `char` is too small for yes or no...

Comment: The If statement is behaving exactly as it should - Where in your code have you written anything to expect input from the user?

Comment: Move `scanf("%d", &option);` up 7 lines. To before where you test the value input.

Comment: This code is perfectly conform to its behavior :) As said by others your `if` depends on values you get from user later.

Comment: ... you should also be more rigorous in testing the input values for `option`. You didn't check for `else if (option == 2)` but assumed it would be. After you have checked it, add `else printf("Sorry I forgot to buy you a present!!");`. The lesson is, build code that won't fall over at a puff of wind.

Comment: note that comparing strings needs to use `strcmp`. And `if (reply == yes)` don't makes many sense in this context, as even without the problem of "yes" (or "no") that can't fit in a char you will compare the char "y" (let say) with the variable "yes" that contains 0.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see a question.

Comment: Perhaps learn to use the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use scanf to get input from the user then take that input,and pass into your if statement argument,and char takes only single character value Ex:-'y' if you want to use "Yes" then either use string or char[].

include

```
int main()
{

char reply;
int option;

printf("Hey M!\n");
printf("Is today your 16th birtday?!\n:Yes=Y or No=N\n");
scanf("%c", &reply); \\ Enter Y or y for Yes

if (reply == 'Y' || reply == 'y') {
    printf("HAPPY BIRTHDAY!! :)\n");
}
else {
    printf("Are you sure??\n");
}

printf("It is time for your super awesome birthday surprise\n\n");
printf("You must choose between one of two presents\n\n");
printf("Please choose between the following options:\n Option 1 or Option 2\n (enter a 1 or a 2)\n\n");

scanf("%d", &option);

if (option == 1) {
    printf("Go look in Mom and Dad's closet!!");
}
else {
    printf("Go look in the storage room!!");
}


printf("HAVE A GREAT SWEET 16!");

return 0;
```

Comment: why is everyone so hostile on here? settle down or don't answer if you can't do so normally. Thanks to anyone who managed that

Answer (score 0):

You write `scanf` statements after the `if` statements and you have to understand that `char yes` is different from the string `"yes"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char reply = 0;
    char no = 0;
    char name = 0;
    int option = 0;


    printf("Hey M!\n");
    printf("Is today your 16th birtday?!\n:yes or no\n");

    scanf("%c", &reply);

    if (reply == 'y') {
        printf("HAPPY BIRTHDAY!! :)\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Are you sure??\n");
    }

    printf("It is time for your super awesome birthday surprise\n\n");
    printf("You must choose between one of two presents\n\n");
    printf("Please choose between the following options:\n Option 1 or Option 2\n (enter a 1 or a 2)\n\n");

    scanf("%d", &option);

    if (option == 1) {
        printf("Go look in Mom and Dad's closet!!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Go look in the storage room!!");
    }

    printf("HAVE A GREAT SWEET 16!");

    return 0;
}
```